# Jsefa - skip column names when loading CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I have CSV file in following format

```
Name,Age
FirstPerson,22
SecondPerson,33
```

Now I am trying to load its content with jsefa library like this

```
Deserializer deserializer = CsvIOFactory.createFactory(Person.class).createDeserializer();
deserializer.open(new FileReader(csvName));

while (deserializer.hasNext()) {
    Person person = deserializer.next();
    System.out.println("person = " + person);
}
```

This prints following result to console

```
person = Person (name=Name, age=Age)
person = Person (name=FirstPerson, age=22)
person = Person (name=SecondPerson, age=33)
```

I wonder if there is proper way to skip first line in the input file. So that I get only FirstPerson and SecondPerson persons, but not Name person.

As for now I can think only of adding this code before while-loop

```
if (deserializer.hasNext()) {
    deserializer.next();
}
```

But it doesn't look very good.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Bad Title. This question has nothing to do with columns...
Should be "skip header row" or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `HeaderAndFooterFilter` to achieve that.

Something like this to set up your deserialiser:

```
CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
config.setLineFilter(new HeaderAndFooterFilter(1, false, true));
Deserializer deserializer = CsvIOFactory.createFactory(config, Person.class)
                                        .createDeserializer();
```

Comment: Can you add how to do the opposite? I want to **write the column names** when writing to a csv?

Comment: @Shubham That seems like a relevant question. I think you should post that as a separate question, though...